# Error in using canvas.toDataURL() in react- native with npm react-native-canvas latest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, canvas

```
    const image = new CanvasImage(canvas);
    canvas.width = 100;
    canvas.height = 100;
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    image.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/c2wRzfD.jpg';
    image.addEventListener('load', async () => {
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 100, 100);
        let dataURL = await canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
    });
```

This code gives me error like:

> "Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined"

This comes only when I `drawImage()` on canvas it works properly when I draw rectangle, round etc.

Android Studio is 3.0.1

node -v is stabble

Comment: How are you `importing` the module, can you post the `import statement`?

Comment: import Canvas, { Image as CanvasImage, Path2D } from 'react-native-canvas';

Comment: Just tested in ios , seems to work fine.

Comment: I am testing this in Android device and i am getting error. Do you have any idea or suggestion for the same?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this cod inside the listener

```
let dataURL = await canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
```

It seems to break your **constructor definition** to the `drawImage`

This can be solved by using it as follows

```
 handleImageRect = async (canvas) => {
        const image = new CanvasImage(canvas);
        canvas.width = 100;
        canvas.height = 100;

        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        image.src = 'https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/unicorn-background-design_1324-79.jpg';
        image.addEventListener('load', () => {
            console.log('image is loaded');
            context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 100, 100);

        });
        // Move it outside
        let dataURL =  await canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
        console.log(dataURL)
    }
```

Comment: If i put await canvas.toDataURL() outside then generating base64 gives me blank image

Comment: Try the `dataURL` log with your debugger mode on, it will log the `base64` for the image and display it. I'm trying on android simulator and it's working.

Comment: Let me know your configurations.if i put the code same as you have given it still gives me blank image. In addition if i add rectangle, circle and image then generating image(.PNG) has only rectangle and circle elements

Comment: Check with the debugger, debug in your `console.log`, it should show the `base64`, sometimes some optimizations are moved to the debugger that you're running, hence improves performance

Comment: Are you getting the base64 in the debugger console? `dataUrl`

Comment: Yes.But this URL does not include image

Comment: I’ll try to add a GitHub repo to it today, you’re using android studio right?

Comment: Yes.And please take note if i do same coding which you have given gives blank image and mine coding gives me error